# Aurelia on a server

Tags: gulp, aurelia, browser-sync

I am trying to run aurelia in my dev environment, but when I close my terminal 'gulp serve' stops running and I get a 503 error.

I have tried running 'gulp server &', and 'nohup gulp serve &' but both times on terminal close the app closes.

How have other people solved this issue? Also, how to you get browser sync to not run with in a production environment? This has been causing issues for me, but I'm not sure how to use gulp without it since it seems to be built in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be running `gulp` tasks in production at all.  They are for development only.  In your production environment you need to find a proper web server like Apache or IIS.  You should also never use Browser Sync as it is only for development.

Comment: wow.. idk why I thought the code would need to be constantly compiled. Thank you, got it working by pointing apache to the directory after running gulp bundle.